# VSTS error TF400813. Can't login. Where do I enter my VSTS credentials?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm working on a UWP project and wanted to check back in my code into Visual Studio Team Services. However, I can't. Visual Studio gave me an error saying that I was off line. I tried to go to manage my connections and connect to VSTS, but that failed, giving me this:

[image]

In the past there was always a link to reenter my credentials, but as you can see from the above error, there is no way of reentered my credentials. Going to Home doesn't work. Where do I reenter my credentials to my VSTS account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Greg Duncan, I've got a way of fixing this. Thought I'd post it in case others experience the same problem.

In Visual Studio, go to Help, Register Product and then Sign Out (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2892152/-client-authentication-required-error-message-after-you-upgrade-from-p which is for VS 2013, but I’ve confirmed it looks the same in VS 2015 and VS 2017)

Answer (score 0):

check with the permission of team services that you are in the readers or stakeholder access level.